# Why am I getting a Django Reslover404 Error?

Tags: python, django

I'm studying Django with djbook and so far created my 'polls' app. It works fine but when I added a log file, there is an error message in it:

```
Exception while resolving variable 'name' in template 'unknown'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 567, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>], [<URLResolver <module 'polls.urls' from '/home/DeadMoroz/mysite/polls/urls.py'> (polls:polls) 'polls/'>]], 'path': ''}


...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 848, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key "
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [name] in <URLResolver <module 'polls.urls' from '/home/DeadMoroz/mysite/polls/urls.py'> (polls:polls) 'polls/'>
Not Found: /
(0.011) SELECT "polls_question"."id", "polls_question"."question_text", "polls_question"."pub_date", "polls_question"."author" FROM "polls_question" WHERE "polls_question"."pub_date" <= '2020-04-28 04:40:16.152659' ORDER BY "polls_question"."pub_date" DESC  LIMIT 5; args=('2020-04-28 04:40:16.152659',)
```

My **'polls/urls.py'** file seems to be the same as in Django Book:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    ]
```

Here's my project file structure:

```
polls/
---logs/
------debug.log
---migrations/
---static/
------polls/
---------images/
------------background.gif
------style.css
---templates/
------admin/
---------base_site.html
------polls/
---------detail.html
---------index.html
---------results.html
---__init.py__
---admin.py
---apps.py
---models.py
---tests.py
---urls.py
---views.py
```

I'm very new to Django, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: error shows problem with url `polls/` in some template - maybe you should use `/` instead of `polls/` in some tamplate ?

Comment: use `/` instead of `polls/` in which file?

Comment: error shows only `django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist:` so it meas some template - you have to check all templates.

Comment: maybe simply use any tool to search string `pool/` in all files - ie. `grep` .

Comment: there are only 3 templates in `polls` app, in one of them `polls/` is used: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">`. I replaced it with `/`. Style disappeared, the error remained

Comment: maybe problem is in different place. Did you run django in debug mode? maybe it gives more useful information. You can also use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox` (tab: `Networks`) to see which url gives error 404.

Comment: or maybe problem is not `pool/` but `/` - last line shows `Not Found: /` and seems you don't have `/` in `urlpatterns`

Comment: I'm sorry, there's one more row in the end of log file (not sure if it has relation with error message) - I've updated the question text

Comment: regarding `/` in urlpatterns - djbook does not suggest it... there's only `''` pattern which is linked with `index.html` page. If I change `''` with `/`there's `page not found` error

Comment: I think problem is you have only one app which has all urls with prefix `pools/` and there is no app with urls without prefix - which could catch `/`

Comment: normally when you generate new project using `django-admin startproject` it creates folder with settings and main `urls.py` which can define function for `/`. And every app has own `urls.py` and every url has the same prefix - ie. `pools/` or `admin/`

Comment: the error occurs when I click on the link on the page `http://deadmoroz.pythonanywhere.com/polls/` and go to the page `http://deadmoroz.pythonanywhere.com/polls/1/`

Comment: run code on your local computer to see all errors in console - and when it will work correctly then send it on server.

Comment: On this page you have only link `http://deadmoroz.pythonanywhere.com//1` - without `polls` - and it can be your problem. You created wrong url in template. You have `/` but you need `pool/` in template

Comment: I see this in a page source code:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/polls/style.css">
    <ul>    
        <li><a href="/polls/1/">Не лает, не кусает, а в дом не пускает</a></li>    
    </ul>`
It seems there's `polls` there... or I missed something?

Comment: check you html file where you are using "name". that should be an id because your url is only configured to match the id

Comment: found one:
`<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>`
is there something wrong?